# How to drop all MySQL tables using drush?

Tags: drush

Normally I could drop and create database from scratch, but what if user doesn't have permission to do that?

Also I wouldn't like to specify my credentials in the command-line (1. it's hard to type, especially complex passwords, 2. it's not safe as it get stored in shell history files and on the process list).

Therefore how I can drop all tables using drush?

---

Related:

- [How to drop all MySQL tables from the command-line?](https://superuser.com/questions/308071/drop-all-table-in-mysql-database-using-terminal)
- [MySQL DROP all tables, ignoring foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476765/mysql-drop-all-tables-ignoring-foreign-keys)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It seems there is a single drush command to Drop all tables in a given database. Just run:

```
$ drush sql-drop
```